# Error running Google video intelligence API code

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-python

I am trying to use the Video Intelligence API code provided on GitHub by google cloud, here is the link to the code: `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/video/cloud-client/analyze/analyze.py`

When I am trying to run the code I get the following error:

> google.gax.errors.RetryError: GaxError(Exception occurred in retry
>   method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of
>   RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, Google Cloud
>   Video Intelligence API has not been used in project
>   usable-auth-library before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/videointelligence.googleapis.com/overview?project=usable-auth-library
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.)>)

The API is already enabled and I have authenticated and tested the authentication by sending a request to GoogleCloud using curl.

Can someone help out with this error?

Comment: Can you add the parts of the code involved in the error, the ones that fail or are related to the problem, etc. Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)